# What is the difference in weight between the minimum spec 2018 15" Macbook Pro and the maximum spec?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Apple's website lists only a single weight for a 2018 15" Macbook Pro

https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/

> Weight: 4.02 pounds (1.83 kg)<sup>3</sup>
>
> <sup>3: Weight varies by configuration and manufacturing process.</sup>

So with memory, storage, cpu and gpu maxxed out what is the difference in weight?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there’s any difference at all. Perhaps a few tens grams, but nothing that would change that it is about 1,8 kg.

Comment: There will be a difference -- you can't go from a 512GB SSD to a 4 TB SSD without adding chips -- but it won't be much.

Comment: @Mark yes, that’s what the additional tens of grams are for. Those extra flash chips really do not weigh much. CPU’s are the same weight no matter which CPU frequency, etc.